# how to stop / start timer on server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

there is a timer that is on the server set for a specific time. The question is how you can make a button in the admin panel so that you can start the timer from the button, and not so that it constantly works.

For example, I need that when I press a button in the admin panel, a timer for 2 hours will start, but for all users. Thanks in advance.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  // var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    // 'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
} 

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  // var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('#hh');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('#mm');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('#ss');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    // daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline="July 25 2021 20:25:00 GMT+0300"; // точная дата
 // var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) +  24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // точное время
initializeClock('countdown', deadline);
```

Comment: This really depends on the purpose of the timer.  Is something supposed to happen when time runs out? How would someone be able to see the timer?

Comment: @Joe Site for a bar game that lasts 2 hours, users have a timer in the navigation bar. The problem is how to make sure that the admin can turn it on and off from the button.